# How to prevent others to embed my flash?

Tags: flash, security, embed, policy

I have a flash file developed with Flex/ActionScript and put it on www.domainA.com

How can I prevent others to download my flash (*.swf) and to embed it in other web site (e.g. www.domainX.com) ?

I can hard code it by checking if "loaderinfo.url" is the same as www.domainA.com, but it seems not a clever solution.

can policy file be useful (e.g. crossdomain.xml) and with Security.loadPolicy(...)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to to this.
Esiest one you already did it:
- hardcode your domain in the flash app and check for it
- put a custom policy file on your website and do not put a crossdomain file (it means you can load it locally, but it can't be loaded from other websites)
- play with flashvars and local files

An swf movie is like a jpeg file, it works anywhere. Someone really really clever could just find out the way you use to prevent it's functionalities. I think after all hard-coding the url it should come from and check for it is the best solution, especially if then you encrypt the swf file using something such as amayeta flash encrypt...

I hope it helped...
P